# How to implement interface for Golang callback functions?

Tags: go, interface, callback

I would like implement `wrap` to take in both `helloSlice` and `hello` without having an additional `wrapSlice`. Is there a way to achieve this. Thank you in advance.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func helloSlice(a string) []string {
    time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
    return []string{"helloSlice" + a}
}

func hello(a string) string {
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
    return "hello" + a
}

func wrap(a string, fn func(string) string) string {
    fmt.Print("Good Morning and ... \n")
    return fn(a)
}

func wrapSlice(a string, fn func(string) []string) []string {
    fmt.Print("Good Morning and ... \n")
    return fn(a)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(wrap(" people", hello))
    fmt.Println(wrapSlice(" people", helloSlice))
}
```

Comment: No, not until generics are fully implemented. You could use interface{} as return type, but that's ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your want?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Callback func(x string) interface{}

func wrap(a string, callback Callback) interface{} {
    return callback(a)
}

func helloSlice(a string) interface{} {
    time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
    return []string{"helloSlice" + a}
}

func hello(a string) interface{} {
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
    return "hello" + a
}

/*
func wrap(a string, fn func(string) string) string {
    fmt.Print("Good Morning and ... \n")
    return fn(a)
}

func wrapSlice(a string, fn func(string) []string) []string {
    fmt.Print("Good Moring and ... \n")
    return fn(a)
}
*/
func main() {
    //fmt.Println(wrap(" people", hello))
    //fmt.Println(wrapSlice(" pepople", helloSlice))
    fmt.Println(wrap(" people", hello))
    fmt.Println(wrap(" people", helloSlice))
}
```